# How can I slow down the CALayer.transform animation?

Tags: ios, animation, transform, duration

I currently have to a layer (CALayer) that I scale between these scales to create an animation.

```
private let invisibleScale = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.0,0.0,1.0)
private let fullScale = CATransform3DMakeScale(2.5,2.5,1.0)
```

By simply calling the below functions on my layer the layer animates just like I want it to (except a bit to fast).

```
animationLayer.transform = invisibleScale
animationLayer.transform = fullScale
```

I have tried to add CABasicAnimation with the transform as the value but that doesn't work since it goes back to the original scale after finishing the animation. Something like this:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
animation.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: invisibleScale)
animation.duration = animationDuration
animationLayer.add(animation, forKey: "transform")
```

So I tried adding the animationLayer.transform = fullScale at the end to update the state after the animation.

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
animation.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: invisibleScale)
animation.duration = animationDuration
animationLayer.add(animation, forKey: "transform")
animationLayer.transform = fullScale
```

This results in an animation that looks exactly the same as just calling:

```
animationLayer.transform = fullScale
```

I've also tried stuff like:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
        self.animationLayer.transform = fullScale
}
```

That also animates with the same speed as just typing animationLayer.transform = invisibleScale.

Any tips for how to make this work would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally found a solution using CATransaction!

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
animationLayer.transform = transform
CATransaction.commit()
```